# i am not able to add this lao font link in my html file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add this font as you can see but it is not working

@font-face {font-family: myfont; src: url(http://www.eaglefonts.com/truetype-lao-fonts-259.htm);}

This is the font link:

http://www.eaglefonts.com/truetype-lao-fonts-259.htm

Comment: ***as you can see but it is not working*** Where are you expecting us to see?

Comment: font file needed

Comment: You are pointing to a webpage which (amongst other things) has a list of fonts but is not itself a font file. Fonts files have various types (see eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face for examples). You need to find the font you want to use and a file with that font in it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: <font name>;
  src: url("add correct url here");
}
```